# Can I find an affordable long term car rental/lease in USA for 50 days?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, long-term

I am trying to find a answer for an affordable car rental/lease for over 30+ days. My wife and I will be traveling from Italy back to the USA later this year. We will be spending 50+ days in the USA flying into Washington Dulles (IAD) in October and then back to Italy in December. I know about ReadyDrive USA but the downside is they only allow 2,000 miles per month and we plan to visit with family and friends in multiple states. We are looking to rent/lease a SUV because we expect to run into snow while we are there. We have valid NC drivers licenses but no USA car insurance.

Comment: Would buying and selling a second hand not be an option?

Comment: Andra, Thanks for your comment but that is not an option because of the time and expense involved.

Comment: What is "affordable" to you?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3620/444

Comment: Closing as duplicate because @Flimzy's answer helps but I think it is not exactly the same. The question is for rental agencies that offer long rentals, but list-questions are not very welcome here. I would suggest to use kayak, expedia or the kind and compare prices. For rental cars in general, every offer has different terms (which may change depending on states, on the time, ...), so you should just compare each depending on your needs. (There are brokers which offer unlimited kilometers if it's what you want)