# Does having a US drivers' license reduce car insurance versus a Dutch drivers' license in the US?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, automobiles, driving-licenses

I am currently studying in Buffalo, NY and have no need for a car.
However, I may want to go on a road trip and the end of my stay on the west coast.
Will it make insurance cheaper to get a driving licence here if I want to rent or buy a car for 4 weeks? I am in possession of a Dutch driving licence.

Also, do they make a distinction between in-state and out-of-state licences when renting a car?

Comment: There is a difference in insurrance based on license?

Comment: This is something I heard from others. But Insurance companies don't really give you information about the costs when using a foreign licence.

Comment: What is your legal status in the US? Are you a visitor (eg, VWP, B1/B2 visa, etc) or a resident (permanent or non-permanent)?

Comment: I have a student visa (F1).

Comment: I think this question is on-topic here since it's about going on a road trip with some unusual requirements, but I think it would definitely also be on-topic in expats.SE since it's about regulations and paperwork while living abroad. Please consider [supporting the expats proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) since you may have more questions relevant to living overseas that would be beyond travel.SE's scope.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3620/444

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exact requirements vary from state to state, but in New York it appears that there is no requirement for you to get a NY Drivers License (as opposed to some other states where once you have been a resident for more than 3 months your home country drivers license is no longer valid).

However on a J1 visa you can optionally get a local drivers license, as long as your visa length is greater than 1 year, AND you have at least 6 months of validity on the visa remaining.

As far as whether it's worth doing this for the purpose of insurance, it depends on what type of insurance you are after.

For rental car insurance, there is no difference in cost of the insurance depending on the type of license you have. If you are getting the insurance from the rental car company (CDP/LDW/etc) then they will not vary it depending on the type of license you have.  If you are getting it via travel insurance or credit card insurance then again it will not vary based on your license - but be sure to read the fine print to make sure it's covered!

If you are looking at buying a car, then it will make a difference, but be prepared for a shock either way. Many insurance companies will not offer you insurance if you do not have a US drivers license.  I've been told there are some that will - especially for medium-term tourists - but expect to pay a lot for it.

If you do have a US drivers license then you will be able to get coverage, but it will not be cheap. Every insurance company I've ever looked at will ask you how long you've been licensed in the US, and will penalize you heavily for anything below 18 months/3 years/5 years (depending on the company). Most will also ask how long you've held a license in another country, and may reduce the price slightly due to your overseas license - but it won't be by much.

Plugging your details, along with those of the type of car you might consider buying, into some of the insurance companies websites will probably be very telling for you - both in terms of whether they will allow you to purchase coverage without a US license, and how much they will charge with only 1-2 months license history in the US.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but do you have evidence that the insurance costs are the same regardless of the type of license you have?  It's trivial to do a search on European travel websites and US travel websites for rental cars in the US and see that you get much cheaper rates through European travel websites.

Comment: Rental car prices, and potentially CDW cost, do indeed vary based on the "point of sale" of the rental (eg, the location of the website you use to book it). Most European "points of sale" will include CDW in US-based rentals.  However none of that has anything to do with the type/location of license that you have...