# Long term Car rental in Europe

Tags: germany, car-rentals, automobiles, long-term

There is a question here about [Car buying vs. long term rentals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/car-rental-vs-buying-a-car-for-1-month) as it relates to the US.

Recently I've driven through Europe renting a car in Frankfurt for about 21 days from Sixt and I was wondering if there was a better option to do long term rentals like this in Frankfurt or any other major hubs in Europe so I don't need to pay for the car at a daily rate?

If it's too broad I am perfectly happy limiting this to Germany.

P.S.  I've checked my usual go to services like Turo and Toyota Rentals and they don't seem to be available in Germany.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using solutions like renting to individuals? There are few websites allowing you to rent cars from individuals rather than regular renting companies. You get the same insurance and coverage but it is usually cheaper.

Links :

http://www.ouicar.fr/

https://carclub.easycar.com/

Comment: Added some links :)

Comment: Apparently the first website is only for France, the second for U.S. and the last for UK. Interesting idea nonetheless.

Comment: [tamyca](https://www.tamyca.de) and [drivy](https://www.drivy.de) are the most popular ones in Germany. [carunity](https://www.carunity.com/de) and [SnappCar](https://www.snappcar.de/) also exist, the latter one is the most popular one in the Netherlands

Comment: I have conaodered Turo,fromeely known as RelayRides.  It is in the question.

Comment: @sitic Add this as an answer.

Comment: I removed [Turo](http://www.turo.com) because they don't operate in Europe

Answer (score 1):

As of December 14, 2016 [Turo](https://blog.turo.com/news/turo-launches-in-the-united-kingdom?utm_campaign=:free:wu:161215_UKAnnounce_CAN&utm_medium=free:email&utm_source=whatcounts) has expanded its operations to United Kingdom though still it wouldn't have helped me in Germany at the time of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at short term leasing in stead. There are several companies offering this, many taking advantage of some peculiarities in French tax law.

Just use google. Several good deals are available, for rentals starting at 21 days up to 6 months. Most will give you a new vehicle for the duration.