# How can I rent a high clearance vehicle in the US?

Tags: usa, car-rentals

For a vacation in the southwest USA, we're considering renting a high-clearance vehicle to visit locations such as the [Toroweap overlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroweap_Overlook) (also known as Tuweep overlook).  Regular car rental classifications appear to classify cars as "Small", "Medium", "Large", "SUV" (all cheap), "Luxury", "Van", or "Convertible" (all expensive).  I don't know if any of those may be expected to be high clearance.  Independent companies rent actual Jeep Wranglers but judging from cars I've seen on similar high clearance roads in the past, a car like the Jeep Wrangler is overkill.  How can I specifically rent a high clearance vehicle, without going all the way to specialised jeep rentals which would triple the rental price?

---

NB: See also [this sister question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/105510/2509) on whether terms and conditions would allow driving on unpaved dirt roads at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69014/discussion-on-question-by-gerrit-how-can-i-rent-a-high-clearance-vehicle).

Comment: Enterprise rents Wranglers for fairly reasonable prices.  Have fun!

Comment: You simply can not take rental cars "off road", just forget it.  (there are a handful of specialized places that rent them, sometimes unregistered on a trailer, but it's irrelevant to your needs.)

Comment: And FWIW as others have said, the whole idea of being able to take on a difficult trail (assuming it is a difficult trail) because you have a vehicle with "high clearance" is nonsensical.  It would be like me saying: "I'm really interested in boxing against Floyd Mayweather. Which gloves should I buy?"  Or it would be like if I said "I noticed the Beatles have made a lot of money. Which guitar should I buy to do that?" Heh !!  :)

Comment: @Fattie Although I admit that I don't actually know the difficulty of those specific roads, this is a regularly frequented road to an NPS [campsite](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/tuweep.htm) and [trailhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckup_Trail) we're talking about, not some remote jungle track through Papua or the [Alexander Mackenzie Heritage Trail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrWdnFflDKk). I don't agree that driving to an NPS campground or trailhead, where the last 4 km are "high clearance", is comparable to boxing against Mayweather or becoming as famous as the Beatles.

Comment: @CramerTV Could you show how? Going through Enterprise's [website](https://www.enterprise.com) and selecting their St. George office, they list SUVs and pickup trucks but not Jeeps.

Comment: hey @gerrit - difficulty of trail:  **by all means** it may, actually, be a completely easy trail.  it's impossible to know unless you seek local knowledge.  it's worth noting that you cannot, really, even take a rental car on to a good but unsurfaced road.  You just can't

Comment: hey @gerrit - regarding **renting a Wrangler**.  This is confusing, but understand that: (1) of about 5 million Wranglers in the USA, 4,990,000 are used *as normal cars, which just look cool*.  They have never, ever, ever been anywhere near a dirt road (far less actual rock hopping).  If you think this is strange, whacky, amazing, whatever, that's nice but that's the fact. Note that (2) it is utterly commonplace for the mainstream rental companies to rent Wranglers, particularly in "cool" cities, ***BUT THEY ARE ABSOLUTELY NOT*** for offroad use.

Comment: Just like any other car you rent from Budget, you (of course, obviously) cannot take them on dirt roads at all for any reason.  Again this may sound strange, whacky, whatever, but you'll have to get over that, as all us foreigners do!  For example, whenever I was on a shoot in LA, I would indeed rent two cars, a Town Car, and a Wrangler.  Like, the only place i would drive is between the Mondrian and a bar, but - who doesn't want a Wrangler?  Again this may seem counterintuitive, surprising!, whatever, but the Wranglers you can (easily) rent from the normal companies, CAN NOT go on dirt, no.

Comment: Note that - you can trivially rent a Ferrari, etc, from Budget in Los Angeles.  **Does that mean you are allowed to speed in it?**  No, in fact if you speed in a Ferrari from Budget, and scratch it, you get to give them the entire value of a new replacement.  So it's "no astonishing mystery" that the Wranglers, Humvees etc you rent from Budget, you can not take offroad.

Comment: Yes, there are a few extremely specialized places that will literally rent you a set of rock-hoppers for off road, well, rock hopping. (I very much doubt they'd rent out "one" - you only go rock hopping in a group.)  Honestly I doubt these specialist facilities have any relevance to your needs.

Comment: And @gerrit, regarding your **sister question**. The amount of blether on that page is - incredible.  I put in the actual answer for the record!

Comment: I don't think the speeding analogy is right. Speeding is a traffic violation, driving on a public dirt road is not. I (now) recognise that regular car rental companies mostly do not permit driving on dirt roads, some specialised ones do and charge [220$/day](http://southernutahadventurecenter.com/southern-utah-jeep-rentals/). I accept your point that many people drive Jeep Wranglers without ever going on a dirt road, I don't understand them, but the psychology of that choice is beyond the scope of this question (I would also never rent a Ferrari).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69063/discussion-between-gerrit-and-fattie).

Comment: Related question on Law.SE: [*Does a rental car contract violation equate car theft?*](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/24300/3569).

Answer (score 17):

You're not the first to want this.  This means a couple things.  First, the national car rentals are savvy to the requirements of driving in the area, and can counsel you, and may  have offerings for your needs.

Second, you are a newbie to this, and they see a dozen people a day who want to off-road but not pay.  They know how to head them off or **find artful ways to rob them blind**. Off-road specialty rentals charge more because their genuine risk is more.  Which makes it *plain fraud* to use false pretenses to get street-driving prices, and gives sly off-roaders no defense against a $1000 cleaning charge or $2000 for "suspension repairs".  You don't want to get caught up in that meat grinder.

The answer is, contact the auto rental's local office, who knows the territory, and tell them what you plan to use the car for. Ask for their best rate under those conditions. Get a usage waiver in writing, because words mean nothing. Then check with your own insurance too.

I know you're not off-roading, but a [406MHz ELT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon_station) is a really, really, really good thing to have.  Hokey things like "[SPOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPOT_Satellite_Messenger)" are not the same.

Comment: My SPOT has worked flawlessly for the last 4 years while riding motorcycles in the California deserts and mountains. I recommend one to anyone who may be out of cell phone range, whether they are in the back country or in the middle of a large body of water. Beacons are great too but the SPOT allows a Distress call to first responders, a Help message to whomever you've identified for help, and a customizable message to whomever you set it up to go to. It also allows folks to see where you are using the world wide web (if you turn it on and give them the link.) *I* would never call it hokey.

Answer (score 9):

You will not be able to specifically reserve a High Clearance vehicle since that is not an feature most agencies surface.  An alternative is of course specialty agencies.

However, you can ultimately choose a High Clearance vehicle by working the system just a bit.  Here's some tips:

1. High Clearance is >=8 inches (20 cm) and many SUVs (Sport Utility Vehicles) meet this.
2. Book a mid-sized or higher SUV but prepare to be flexible on features and price.
3. Bing and Google are  your friend.  When you get to the counter and learn the exactly vehicle, search it with 'ground clearance'.  It's very easy to ask for something else.*  The Agent won't ask what you searching, and if they do, just say 'safety ratings'.
4. You can pre-search the SUVs a particular agency features to save time.

There's lots of YouTube videos on the Toroweap Overlook road, many in apparently factory SUV's.

This site describes the road as 'easy to moderate' and 'suitable for passenger cars':  [AZ Offroading](http://azoffroading.com/arizona-trails/toroweap-overlook/)

*For clarity, this is not at all unusual, to request a different vehicle than the one assigned.  Frequent renters do this to get specific features or even cars they prefer.

Comment: As for the Toroweap Overlook, NPS says only the last 4 km need high clearance.

Comment: @gerrit Yep, but if it's a meter, might as well be a mile. ;)

Comment: I can walk a metre.  I can also walk 4 km, but perhaps not if I need to carry in water for 3 days.

Comment: @gerrit Oh, are saying it's an option to hike the last 4km?  Sure.  I'm saying that if only 1 meter requires high clearance, the entire trail might at well in terms of the vehicle.  But, there aren't many, if any, places to stop so that's not necessarily an option.

Comment: It could be, but this might not be the only high clearance location we might want to visit; for example, the [Whitmore trail](https://www.hikingproject.com/trail/7003308/whitmore-trail) near the [Bar 10 ranch](https://www.bar10.com/) needs high clearance for a much longer distance.

Comment: Kayak indicates SUV as "Toyota RAV4 or similar", this one in particular apparently has a ground clearance of 6.1 inch / 155 mm, so that wouldn't meet the 8 inch / 20 cm from your answer.

Comment: In fact, none of the listed SUVs at Kayak "model or similar" have a ground clearance ≥ 8 inch / 20 cm, so I'm not convinced that this is going to work.

Comment: @gerrit Kayak?  You need to look at the specific agencies, Budget, Avis, Dollar, etc. Note, I said mid size or higher which means Grand Cherokee to a Tahoe.  Each agency may have slightly different ratings.

Comment: @gerrit For clarity, you will not be able to specify exactly a High Clarence vehicle, it is a *process* as I described.

Comment: Have you ever done step 3, "asking for something else"?

Comment: @gerrit **Absolutely.**  Do it regularly to get a care that has Bluetooth or some other useful feature.  It's not unusual at all.  Beware, this will give them an opportunity to upsell you!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option, especially if you're from the US, is to see if you can find a vehicle for sale on the likes of Craigslist. If you can buy a vehicle and drive it for a couple of days, then you can probably sell it for less than it would cost you to rent one. Of course then you still have to deal with the hassle of *selling* it again, depending on your time commitments, maybe that's worth it.

Comment: Buying a vehicle involves paying taxes on the sale.  Even if you bought and sold it for the same price, you'd still have a tax bill to worry about.  And title/registration fees.

Comment: This site has [a question on that alternative](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3620/2509). I very strongly suspect that I can not buy + sell a vehicle after a couple of days for less than it would cost me to rent one (maybe an experienced used car buyer/seller can). And with buying a car, I would have no clue how many days or weeks it would take before I get approved (or rejected!) by an insurance company in order to drive it. Also, I wouldn't want to drive a crappy old car of unknown maintenance state to a remote backroad in the Arizona Strip.

Comment: @JPhi1618 in most (all?) states, you have about 30 days to register. In Arkansas, at least, if you spend less than I think it's $4,600 on the car there's no sales tax due. And the titles come with a handy dandy bill o' sale on the back - several actually, so the car can be sold a couple of times before you have to register it. In Arkansas, as well, your existing insurance (probably) covers the car while you're driving it. Of course specifics will vary by state to state, and renting is probably easier all around, but buying *is* an option a cost-conscious individual could consider.

Comment: @WayneWerner, interesting - I thought you had to register a car in order to sell it unless you were a dealer (only the registered owner _can_ sell it).  I'll have to see what the rules are in Texas.  Thanks for the counterpoint.

Comment: registration in many of the states that require it, also has a residency requirement. western states may be more lax, but in eastern states it is much more restrictive. I would not trust any random vehicle high clearance or not to go trail riding in. The people who do trail riding maintain their vehicles to support that.

Answer (score 3):

We had (almost) exactly the same plan last year when we were camping on [Point Sublime](https://www.google.be/maps/place/Point+Sublime/@36.2025137,-112.2461051,13z). We had booked the largest SUV to drive around the states (even with full insurance), but didn't want to take the risk of getting it stuck in the mud in the middle of nowhere. So we additionally reserved a dedicated off-road jeep locally for two days (all-in cost about $200 for six people).

We got lucky and actually got the biggest car in the lot (Chevrolet Suburban, 4-wheel drive, higher than normal ground clearance). We kept an eye on the weather, checked with a local park ranger, which assured us the road was "in really good conditions" and decided to cancel the jeep and go for it with the Chevy.

Everyone has his own definition of "Good conditions"; we made it, but it was still a difficult ride. If we didn't have that much ground clearance, we would have scraped the bottom of the car over the rocky road or got stuck.

So I'd still advise to get the proper vehicle for the job and definitely inform with the park rangers about road conditions.